# what corresponds string[] in C++\CLI

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I would like to ask and know what corresponds the C# type `string[]` in C++\CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a *managed* array it would be

```
array<String^>^
```